# How to insert data into new table from other table and make sum of two column

Tags: php, mysql

I am using below mysql query to insert data from oldtable to newtable after the user ads money to his account. if user credit some money to his account i want to enter the value of accbal column to be the sum of credit column value and accbal (user older account balance). i.e i want to add mysql row having user account resultant balance after adjusting debit credit amount. Kindly tell me how to do it with mysql and php.

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO newtable (emailadd, credit, debit, accbal, txtime, txnid) SELECT buyeremailaddr, 'balcredit', '0', QUESTION, pptxtime, pptxid FROM oldtable WHERE paymenthash='$item_no' AND paid='1'"; 
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: where do the two values you want to add together live?  if they're both in oldtable, just add them 'accbal + credit' in the select statement.  otherwise you may need to nest another query in there

Comment: the old table does not have accbal value. it is contained in new table only

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: you will have to separate that in to 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

this is probably more complex than you need, but it gets tricky when you're trying to link in the value from the related record with the most recent date:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (
    emailadd
    , credit
    , debit
    , accbal
    , txtime
    , txnid
) SELECT buyeremailaddr
    , 'balcredit'
    , '0'
    , credit + accbal
    , pptxtime
    , pptxid 
FROM oldtable
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT emailadd,accbal FROM newtable JOIN (
            SELECT emailadd
                ,MAX(txtime) AS maxdate 
            FROM newtable GROUP BY emailadd
        ) AS mt ON mt.maxdate = newtable.txtime 
            AND mt.emailadd = newtable.emailadd GROUP BY emailadd
    ) AS nt ON oldtable.buyeremailaddr = nt.emailadd 
WHERE paymenthash='$item_no' 
    AND paid='1'
```

essentially you join to the newtable grouped by email, which is in turn joined to itself again grouped by email in order to compare the txtime to the max txtime to get the most recent accbal value.  warning: this does not scale well with very large tables.  better to create views, or even better, reassess your existing data structure